# Encrypt / decrypt stream of data?

Tags: vb.net

What are the best way to encrypt and decrypt stream of data ?

I would like that my program read a file.. and unencrypt it in memory then when it save it.. it encrpyt the stream and save it.

Dunno if its possible but i would like to do something similar.

Thanks!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.aspx#Y3024 or http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301070/en-us

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can choose from one of the encryption algorithm implementations in the [System.Security.Cryptography](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography) namespace, the documentation for individual algorithms (e.g. the [Rijndael](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged.aspx) crypto provider) includes code examples for encrypting and decrypting streams of data.

Comment: Would you mind if i ask for an exemple ? I am a bit confused. I know there was Crypto function.. but would like to see some useful example.

Comment: The "Rijndael" link above has a VB.NET code sample for encrypting and decrypting a simple string - for your needs you could replace the string in the example code with data you've read in from a file on.

Comment: And what about stream encryption? How to encode/decode streams before writing them anywhere?